# Best in place sending routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a user controller  as follows. I want to use the best_in_place gem for editing name and bio in profile page. I have followed Ryan Bates railscast but its not working correctly. When I tried to see the error through the chrome inspector I see best in place is requesting url http://localhost:3001/user/3 and now throwing 404 not found error.

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:profile]
respond_to :json, :html
def profile
  @user = current_user
end

def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  if current_user.update(user_params)
    respond_with current_user
  end
end

def edit
  @user = current_user
end

private
  def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :bio)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :user
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `routes.rb` you configured routes as `resources :user` which gives following routes:

[image]

But we can see your controller is `UsersController` so you have to configured your routes as: `resources :users` Which gives following routes:

[image]

Hope this may solve your problem.

Comment: @bishisht Could you please accept the answer so that it is clear that the problem is resolved?